# Can the angle of the gradient be made dependent of the width of the container?

Tags: css, fluid-layout, gradient, angle

So I have two adjacent fluid divs that can change their width when the device size changes, when the user changes the font-size of the browser, or when zooming the browser with Ctrl +.

I want to have a diagonal that crosses both divs, like this:

```
_____
|blah|
|blah|
|blah| 
|   /| <--- First div or section
|__/_|
| /  | <--- Second div or section
|/   |
|blah|
|blah|
|blah|
|____| 
<----> fluid width
```

I'm trying to do it with CSS to avoid downloading images and making extra http requests. So I am using  linear gradients. The problem is that the angle of the diagonal must change when the width of its container increases or decreases, otherwise the diagonal breaks.

See a fiddle here: http://dabblet.com/gist/50db5e6220b5ba557b9e

For the record, the code of the above fiddle is:

```
/*
* Diagonal that crosses both divs without breaking
*/
div, p{margin:0;}
div{padding:0 1em;}
.one{
    background: #f06;
    background: linear-gradient(170deg, #f06 80%, yellow 80%, yellow);
    font-size: 200%
}
.two{
    background: yellow;
    background: linear-gradient(170deg, #f06 20%, yellow 20%, yellow);
    font-size: 200%
}
```

And the html:

```
<div class="one"><!-- foo --></div>
<div class="two"><!-- bar --></div>
```

I have tried changing the background-size, background-position, background-origin, the units from em to px, px to %, the color stops, etc. I run out of ideas.

My question is... is there a way to make the angle in the gradient dependent of the width of the container (in some indirect way), so that if it is resized the diagonal changes its angle? I would like a pure CSS solution (no JavaScript).

If this is a problem without solution, is ok =)

Answer (score 4):

You could use this workaround:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <div class="one"><!-- foo --></div>
    <div class="two"><!-- bar --></div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.bg {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #f06 50%, yellow 50%, yellow);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://dabblet.com/gist/28316eb4572ba425aa47)

Comment: @Eric The workaround is setting the background to `.bg` instead of splitting it between `.one` and `.two`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to try! =)
It's a smart idea to have the bg set in another element so that it adapts nicely. However you need to add an extra div for the sake of styling, which is not so nice. BUT, the idea is still cool so [I decided to try with pseudo elements instead (using :before)](http://dabblet.com/gist/ddce1f7be66a01107e4e). The problem is that then the contents of the divs need to have a higher z-index set. I'll keep thinking... Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you may do this using background-size and no-repeat. **[DEMO](http://dabblet.com/gist/afe44495650bc3318bb0)**

```
.one{
    background: #f06;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #f06 50%, yellow 50%, yellow) right  #f06 ; 
    background-size: 50% 100%;  100% 50% ;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    font-size: 200%
}
.two{
    background: yellow;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #f06 50%, yellow 50%, yellow) left yellow ; 
    background-size: 50% 100%;  100% 50% ;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    font-size: 200%
}
```

BUT, this will look funny if both div have different heights: **[DEMO](http://dabblet.com/gist/b2b310b3e5035c80dadc)**

**[You better set the gradient within the parent container (body for your dabblet)](http://dabblet.com/gist/bff6a10cda9527f8768d)** in my own opinion, unless you do want to see the gradient angle breaking.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's true, I was only focusing on the width for the responsive tests but the height also has an effect on the angle. One of the problems of setting the gradient in the parent container is that there will be more than two divs, however your solution gave me more ideas to test. I'll try to find some workaround. Thank you!